# XSLT: скопировать внешний документ, изменив значения атрибутов

Tags: xslt

Преобразование получается из двух файлов. Первый - входной, в котором содержатся значения, которые нужно вставить в нужные места второго файла. Пусть входной файл имеет вид:

```
<tr><td>5, 6</td><td>-6,-5</td></tr>
```

Второй файл открывается в шаблоне преобразования при помощи `document('имяФайла.xml')` и его нужно скопировать в выходной документ, изменив значения атрибутов max. Новые значения берутся из входного документа из элементов `<td>`. Второй файл имеет вид:

```
<a id="id1" min="0,5" max="0,3"/>  
<b id="id2" min="-1,0" max="-3,1"/>
```

Замены производятся соответственно, т.е. первый элемент `id='id1'` получает в атрибут значение из первого элемента `<td>`, а второй элемент `id='id2'` получает значения из второго элемента `<td>`. После всех замен должно получиться следующее.

Шаблон требуется универсальный, т. е. количество элементов `<a>,<b>,<a>...` и `<td>` во входных документах - любое.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">   

<xsl:variable name="file" select="document('имяФайла.xml')"/>  

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:attribute name="max">
      <xsl:value-of select="$file//tr/td[position()]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сформированный xml обязан иметь корневой элемент. Предположим, входной документ имеет вид

```
<root>
    <a id="id1" min="0,5" max="0,3"/>
    <b id="id2" min="-1,0" max="-3,1"/>
</root>
```

На мой взгляд, самое простое решение - не обращать внимания на первый документ, а создавать выходной файл только на основе второго. Шаблон получается элементарный. Количество элементов `<a>,<b>` при этом может быть любым.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('имяФайла.xml')/root/*">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="./@min"/>
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="./@max"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Как вариант, внутри `<td>` можно использовать

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(./@min, ', ', ./@max)"/>
```